# How to apply values in column based on condition in row values in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

df

```
    Name        year    week    date
0   Adam        2016    16  2016-04-24
1   Mary        2016    17  2016-05-01
2   Jane        2016    20  2016-05-22
3   Joe         2016    17  2016-05-01
4   Arthur      2017    44  2017-11-05   
5   Liz         2017    41  2017-10-15
6   Janice      2016    47  2016-11-27
```

And I want to create column season so `df['season']` that attributes a season `MAM` or `OND` depending on the value in `week`.

The result should look like this:

df_final

```
    Name        year    week    date      season
0   Adam        2016    16      2016-04-24 MAM
1   Mary        2016    17      2016-05-01 MAM
2   Jane        2016    20      2016-05-22 MAM
3   Joe         2016    17      2016-05-01 MAM
4   Arthur      2017    44      2017-11-05 OND 
5   Liz         2017    41      2017-10-15 OND
6   Janice      2016    47      2016-11-27 OND
```

In essence, values of `week` that are below `40` should be paired with `MAM` and values above 40 should be `OND`.

So far I have this:

```
condition =df.week < 40
df['season'] = df[condition][[i for i in df.columns.values if i not in   ['a']]].apply(lambda x: 'OND')
```

But it is clunky and does not produce the final response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
condition = df.week < 40
df['season'] = np.where(condition, 'MAM', 'OND')
print (df)
     Name  year  week        date season
0    Adam  2016    16  2016-04-24    MAM
1    Mary  2016    17  2016-05-01    MAM
2    Jane  2016    20  2016-05-22    MAM
3     Joe  2016    17  2016-05-01    MAM
4  Arthur  2017    44  2017-11-05    OND
5     Liz  2017    41  2017-10-15    OND
6  Janice  2016    47  2016-11-27    OND
```

EDIT:

For convert `string`s to `integer`s use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
condition = df.week.astype(int) < 40
```

Or convert column:

```
df.week = df.week.astype(int)
condition = df.week < 40
```

Comment: This doesn't work with my actual data where `week` is: Name: week, Length: 1227, dtype: object. The output just returns 'OND' for all. Do I need to change the format of `week`? @jezrael